# ExtJs4 dynamically load items in a toolbar

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

**How can I dynamically load items in an ExtJs 4 toolbar ? I want to load the items from JSON.**

I have tried the loader, but it just became headache.

```
Ext.define('Backend.view.Nav' ,{
    alias: 'widget.Nav',
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
        {
            iconCls: 'freewinder',
            text: 'Freewinder'
        },
        {
            iconCls: 'application',
            text: 'Applikationen',
            xtype: 'splitbutton'
        },
        {
            iconCls: 'component',
            text: 'Komponenten',
            xtype: 'splitbutton'
        },
        '-',
        {
            emptyText: 'Suche ...',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }];     
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `add` method of `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar` to add items dynamically after the toolbar has been constructed: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-method-add

How do you want it to work? Should the toolbar appear, make an AJAX request and them add the menu items -- or should the server upon page load give the client-side app some JSON that contains the menu items or how do you want it to work exactly?

In case of the server outputting JSON on page load you can just do `this.items = jsonItems`.

Comment: i want server outputted json. this.items = jsonItems seems to be wonderful but i dont get it. hieres my code: ... Ext.define('Backend.view.Nav' ,{
 alias: 'widget.Nav',
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    initComponent: function() {
     var me = this; 
     var store = Ext.create('Backend.store.Nav');
  store.load(function() {
   me.items = store;
  }); ...

Comment: Because the XMLHttpRequest (AJAX request) you make completes way after the toolbar is constructed/built. You must have the items loaded before that `initComponent` is run.

Comment: i dont get it! how can i load remote json data into my toolbar (buttons etc.) ... has nobody an example? ive searched all the time now ... :(